# Vue Ionic template logic getting null data objects when data assigned inside async method

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, async-await, vue-data

**UPDATE**
Solution found, but I don't understand the reason. any explanation, please.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I have a Vue / Ionic project which is giving me hell.

I'm trying to use the following code, but problems starts when I try to assing a value to some `data` inside an `async method`.

It seems to assing correctly but some elements in the template can't find the content further than the level 0 of nesting, as shown in the images below.
If I try to reach an `object` property, the `object` seems to be `null` when not null at all.

```
<template>
    <h6>{{proyectos}}</h6> <!--THIS WORKS OK-->
    <!-- <h6>{{proyectos[0]}}</h6> THIS DOESN'T -->
    <!-- <h6 v-if='proyectos[0]'>hola</h6> NEITHER THIS-->
    <div
        v-for='proyecto in proyectos'
        :key='proyecto.id'
    >
        <h3>{{proyecto.id}} - {{proyecto.nombre}}</h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            proyectos: null,
        }
    },

    methods: {  
        async misproyectosIniciar(){
            await this.$store.dispatch('actObtenerProyectos'); //REQUIRES AWAIT
        },

        obtenerProyectos(){
            return this.$store.getters.proyectos;
        },
    },

    async beforeMount(){
        await this.misproyectosIniciar();
        this.proyectos = this.obtenerProyectos();
        console.log('proyectos', this.proyectos);
        console.log('proyectos[0]', this.proyectos[0]);
    },
};
</script>
```

I removed all ionic components, since it always causes me problems.

If I just use the `v-for`, everything works fine.

[image: image of it working fine]

If I uncomment any of the two lines at the top of the code (`{{}}`, `v-if`), then errors show up.

[image: image of it NOT working]

**I have no idea why this is happening, any clues, please?.**
*NOTE: It does requires `await` since is a database query.*

Comment: do you know how async works?

Comment: @bill.gates with black magic, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the object seems to be null when not null at all

Thats not true. At the very begin, your property value is indeed `null`. Lets say your query takes about 1 sek to fetch the data, so only after 1 sek you assign an value to it, and then its not `null` anymore.

So your value is for 1 sek, `null` in this example.

Look, `async / await` does not execute code in sync.

Imagine your database call takes about 1 second to retreive some data.

While your code is fetching the data, vue tries to render the `v-for` but the value is `null` because in the background the data is being fetched.

Also, always (well almost always) initialize arrays with `[]` not with `undefined` `null` or something other.

`[]` works because of this reason:

`null` didnt worked, because you basically tried to do this:

```js
null.forEach(() => {})
```

You basically tried to loop over `null`, and if you know javascript you will know that this does not work.

But if you initialize it with `[]` you actually can loop over, even if there is nothing in it

```js
[].forEach(() => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I just needed to change

```
data(){
    return{
        proyectos: null,
    }
},
```

to

```
data(){
    return{
        proyectos: [],
    }
},
```